# What does "()" do in python log config

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging, uvicorn

I have seen a python dict log config in [**uvicorn**'s](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/f6239169708adcf27433cb8d133e48f8835f0fa2/uvicorn/config.py#L59) source code.

In that, they have defined *formatters* as

```
{
    "default": {
        "()": "uvicorn.logging.DefaultFormatter",
        "fmt": "%(levelprefix)s %(asctime)s %(message)s",
        "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",

    },
    "access": {
        "()": "uvicorn.logging.AccessFormatter",
        "fmt": '%(levelprefix)s %(asctime)s :: %(client_addr)s - "%(request_line)s" %(status_code)s',
        "use_colors": True
    },
}
```

also, we can see, they defined an empty logger ( not sure what should I call it) as,

```
"": {"handlers": ["default"], "level": "INFO"},
^^^^ - see, Empty key
```

So, here is my questions,

1. What does the **`"()"`** do in ***formatters*** section of python logger?
2. What does the **`""`** do in ***loggers*** section python logger?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This dictionary is used to configure logging with [`logging.config.dictConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig).

The `"()"` key indicates that custom instantiation is required [[source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details)]:

> In all cases below where a ‘configuring dict’ is mentioned, it will be checked for the special '()' key to see if a custom instantiation is required. If so, the mechanism described in [User-defined objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#user-defined-objects) below is used to create an instance; otherwise, the context is used to determine what to instantiate.

In the case of the formatter config in the OP's question, the `"()"` indicates that those classes should be used to instantiate a `Formatter`.

I do not see the empty string in the loggers section of the dictionary, but here are the [related docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details):

> `loggers` - the corresponding value will be a dict in which each key is a logger name and each value is a dict describing how to configure the corresponding Logger instance.
>
> The configuring dict is searched for the following keys:
>
> - `level` (optional). The level of the logger.
> - `propagate` (optional). The propagation setting of the logger.
> - `filters` (optional). A list of ids of the filters for this logger.
> - `handlers` (optional). A list of ids of the handlers for this logger.
>
> The specified loggers will be configured according to the level, propagation, filters and handlers specified.

So a `""` key in the `loggers` dictionary would instantiate a logger with the name `""`, like `logging.getLogger("")`.

---

One might use a custom logging formatter for a variety of reasons. `uvicorn` uses a custom formatter [to log different levels in different colors](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/f6239169708adcf27433cb8d133e48f8835f0fa2/uvicorn/logging.py#L11-L56). The Python Logging Cookbook has an [example of using a custom formatter to use UTC times](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#formatting-times-using-utc-gmt-via-configuration) instead of local times in logging messages.

```
import logging
import time

class UTCFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    converter = time.gmtime

LOGGING = {
    ...
    'formatters': {
        'utc': {
            '()': UTCFormatter,
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(message)s',
        },
        'local': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(message)s',
        }
    },
    ...
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
    logging.warning('The local time is %s', time.asctime())
```

Here is the output. Note that in the first line, UTC time is used instead of local time, because the `UTCFormatter` is used.

```
2015-10-17 12:53:29,501 The local time is Sat Oct 17 13:53:29 2015
2015-10-17 13:53:29,501 The local time is Sat Oct 17 13:53:29 2015
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks. It would be nice if you add an example which shows how *normal formatters* are differ from *custom one*.

Comment: Good idea -- added an example from the python logging cookbook.

Comment: In the case of `utc` formatter, shouldn't be **`fmt`** instead of `format`? because, `fmt` is used in the `__init__()` method of `UTCFormatter` (by inherently from `logging.Formatter`)

Comment: Good question, the config dictionary schema indicates that `"format"` is the correct key. It must be converted to a `fmt` arg before being passed to a `Formatter` object.