# Python logging with dictConfig and using GMT / UTC zone time

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, logging, timezone, utc

I'm trying to configure some logging across multiple modules within a package. These modules may be executed in different containers, possibly in different regions, so I wanted to explicitly use GMT / UTC time for logging.

When I'm reading about the [`Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/logging.html#formatter-objects) class in `logging`, it indicates you can specify `converter` to use either local-time or GMT. I'd like to utilize this feature, in conjunction with `dictConfig` (or possibly `fileConfig`) to specify the configurations for the different modules, but the documentation is sparse with respect to this feature. Everything specified in the config is working, except for the timezone. The log always uses local time. I can include the '%z' formatting specification in `datefmt` to specify offset from GMT, but that breaks the `.%(msecs)03d` formatting.

Below is my code using a defined dictionary and `dictConfig`. Has anyone had any success specifying timezone in the config? is this possible?

```
import json
import logging
from logging.config import dictConfig
import time

DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s : %(name)s : %(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d : %(message)s', 
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S',
            'converter': time.gmtime # also fails with 'time.gmtime', 'gmtime'
        }
    },
    'handlers' : {
            'default': {
                'level': 'NOTSET', 
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'standard',
            }
    }, 
    'loggers': {
            'TEST': { # logging from this module should be logged in DEBUG level
                'handlers' : ['default'], 
                'level': 'INFO', 
                'propagate': False,
            },
    },
    'root': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['default']
    },
    'incremental': False
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dictConfig(DEFAULT_CONFIG)
    logger = logging.getLogger('TEST')
    logger.debug('debug message') # this should not be displayed if level==INFO
    logger.info('info message')
    logger.warning('warning message')
    logger.error('error message')
```

Output:

> INFO : TEST : 2022-07-07 17.20.13.434 : info message
> WARNING : TEST : 2022-07-07 17.20.13.435 : warning message
> ERROR : TEST : 2022-07-07 17.20.13.435 : error message

Comment: instead of using the `'converter'` key, call for a custom instantiation by setting `'()': yourTimeFormatterClass`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62956046/10197418

Comment: Hey @FObersteiner How to do the same while using fileConfig ?